How do I get the depth and original strength of a radioactive source from 2 measurements taken at a known offset from each other (inverse square law)
I want to estimate the depth and strength of a buried radioactive source. The drop off is governed by the inverse square law. If a very strong source measures 5uSv/hr at the surface because it's deep it will drop off slower as you move farther away than a shallow source measuring 5uSv/hr because the source strength was low. I want to leverage that to compare 2 scintillators set a known distance apart from each other to try to estimate the non attenuated strength and depth of the source. What would the equation for this look like? An explanation of how you arrived at that equation would be appreciated because I want to understand how the math works. If you have research papers on the rate of attenuation of gamma radiation in soil feel free to share that too.
I am also open to any other ideas on how to achieve the same result. I already have a backup idea to find the center of a source with a vertically orientated detector and then utilize a second collimated detector on a pivot. The angle where the peak reading was achieved could be measured and the Pythagorean theorem used to estimate the adjacent leg.
Any help is greatly appreciated.


How do I get the depth and original strength of a radioactive source from 2 measurements taken at a known offset from each other ?

Even if we can assume that the soil attenuates the radiation intensity at a constant rate, and we also ignore background radiation, there are still four unknowns in this problem - the horizontal location of the source (2 degrees of freedom), the depth of the source and its strength. You can't possibly get a unique solution from just two measurements. You will need at least four measurements at different surface locations, and ideally more than this to be sure you have eliminated other contributing factors.

The horizontal unknowns are mostly solved by moving the detector in a search pattern to try to find the strongest reading from the surface. The terrain and geometry of the source introduces error but generally the x y coordinate are pretty closely represented by the location of the strongest surface reading at least in my application. Would the problem be solvable if the source strength and depth were still unknown? I was thinking of making a soil offset function through experimental data but I want to solve this problem in air first.
